# How to scroll and zoom in/out large images on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image-manipulation, tiles

I have a large image, size around 30000 (w) x 6000 (h) pixels. You may consider it's like a big map. I assume I need to crop it up into smaller tiles. Questions:

- what are the right `ViewControllers` to use?
- ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726335/how-to-tile-a-30000-x-6000-image-for-a-480-x-320-screen)) what is the tile strategy? (I put this in another question, as it's not iPhone specific)

Requirements:

- whole image (though cropped) can be scrolled up/down/left/right by swipes
- zoom in (up to pixel-to-pixel) out (down to screen-fit-by-height) by the 2-finger operation
- memory efficiency by lazy loading tiles

Bonus requirements:

- automatic scroll, say from left to right slowly and smoothly

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out part 3 of Apple's [ScrollViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code for an example of how to do this.