# ipad memory warning on huge patternimage

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, background-color

I have built a zoomable scrollview with a pattern image background.

```
cntView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"patternStripe.png"]];
```

the scrollview is very long and zoomable.

and of coure: i recieve memory warnings (lvl 1 & 2)

**is there a workaround to have pattern images in large zoomable views?**

Comment: How big is your pattern image ? And does it need to zoom as well or is it OK if it stays fixed ?

Comment: its 10x1800 and it has to zoom :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either find a way to reduce the size of the pattern. Does it really need to be 1800px in height, is there no repetition in that pattern already ?

Or you will have to split the pattern background up into smaller images and create a view that draws them as needed and use that view as background/parent view for your content. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726335/how-to-tile-a-30000-x-6000-image-for-a-480-x-320-screen) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679925/how-can-i-use-cgcontextdrawtiledimage-to-tile-an-image).

Apple says to [avoid images larger than 1024x1024](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and while this doesn't exactly fit your image, the fact that you use it as a pattern where it is copied a lot *in whole* before getting cropped likely breaks the barrier.

Comment: i tried with 10x600 still memory warning lvl 2. thaught there might be  a simple "one line solution". i think i will implement a "tile based solution"